# DataTables Searching and Sorting not working for dynamically added Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a DataTable where I need to insert/append data dynamically from an AJAX call. Searching and Sorting on this kind of DataTable does not seem to work as intended. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sg8o8vpv/)

Code:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
       "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "aaData": md,
        "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
        "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
                $('td', row).eq(0).append('<u><a target="_blank" href="' + data["Data"][0].Link + '">' + data["Data"][0].Value + '</a></u>');
                $('td', row).eq(1).append(data["Data"][1].Value);
                $('td', row).eq(1).prop('title', data["Data"][1].Value);
                for (var i = 2; i < data["Data"].length; i++) {
                    if (data["Data"][i].Value == "green") {
                        $('td', row).eq(i).addClass('highlight1');
                        $('td', row).eq(i).append(data["Data"][i].Value);
                    }
                    else if (data["Data"][i].Value == "red") {
                        $('td', row).eq(i).addClass('highlight3');
                        $('td', row).eq(i).append(data["Data"][i].Value);
                    }
                    else if (data["Data"][i].Value == "blue") {
                        $('td', row).eq(i).addClass('highlight2');
                        $('td', row).eq(i).append(data["Data"][i].Value);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('td', row).eq(i).append(data["Data"][i].Value);
                    }
              }
        },
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "fixedColumns": {
           "leftColumns": 2,

        },
        "sScrollXInner": "150%",
        "fixedHeader": true,
        "columnDefs": [{
            "defaultContent": "",
            "targets": "_all",
            "data": null,
            "render":  {
              //  "_":spData[0].Cells[2].Value,
            }
        }],
    } );
```

Any Solutions or ideas to this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe `createdRow` is doing what you intend.  According to the DataTables [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow):

> This callback is executed when a TR element is created (and all TD child elements have been inserted), or registered if using a DOM source, allowing manipulation of the TR element.

Your `<td>` child elements are being rendered by `createdRow` and the searching and sorting features are not aware of their existence.

You should, instead, use `row.add()` if you want to add your rows after `DataTable()` has initialized.  More information on it can be found in the DataTable [doucmentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()).  But here is an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremysouthard/sg8o8vpv/1/) based on your original link using `row.add()` to add your rows to the table, allowing the searching and sorting to now work on them.

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy Southard ! That solution worked for me !